# Onboard Keyboard on Raspberry Pi Lite Kiosk

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to get Onboard keyboard setup on a Raspberry Pi kiosk.

I have setup a kiosk to replace Google Nest Hub Max.  I basically used [this](https://desertbot.io/blog/raspberry-pi-touchscreen-kiosk-setup), installed onboard `sudo apt-get install onboard`, set it up to open on startup by adding `onboard &` to /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart.

It appeared on startup and I used the setting in the app to enable auto-hide.  However, on the next restart it did not appear(expected) but will not show up no matter what I do.

I've tried manually displaying the app with `onboard -display :0` through ssh.  It returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/onboard", line 35, in <module>
    from Onboard.OnboardGtk import OnboardGtk as Onboard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/OnboardGtk.py", line 47, in <module>
    from Onboard.KbdWindow import KbdWindow, KbdPlugWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/KbdWindow.py", line 48, in <module>
    config = Config()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/Config.py", line 214, in __new__
    cls.self.construct()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/Config.py", line 315, in construct
    self._init_logging(min_level_name, max_level_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/Config.py", line 599, in _init_logging
    root.setLevel(min_level_name.upper())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1417, in setLevel
    self.level = _checkLevel(level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 194, in _checkLevel
    raise ValueError("Unknown level: %r" % level)
ValueError: Unknown level: 'ISPLAY'
```

I've already posted on the Launchpad for the app but the last modification on the code was 2017-10-09 and the only response I received was "junk removal in dubai"